# How do I send an IM from visual Basic 2005?

Tags: vb.net, communication

I would like to know how to send an "instant message" (IM) to a recipient on one of the popular IM programs (AIM, MSN, Yahoo, etc.) from a Visual Basic 2005 application.  I would appreciate seeing sample code.

Thanks,

Victor
   victor@yoga.com

Answer (score 2):

use the libpurple library, which is what gaim/pidgin uses

http://developer.pidgin.im/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at AIM specifically, there is a set of URL's which can be formed to allow interaction between aim and HTML link enabled languages:

ie:
    aim:AddBuddy?ScreenName=mytestsn;GroupName=TestGroup3

see for details:

http://dev.aol.com/aimclient/OpenAIM168/technotes/AIMURL.html